# Using Rails console to query multiple models with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying use the rails console to code my statement and below is the relationship of my model:

```
class Lead < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :leads
    belongs_to :stores
end

class Store < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end
```

With this, I'm suppose to find the lead of each store from the last 7 days.  So far, I'm able to find ALL leads with each store by using:

```
s1 = Store.find 1
s1.users.map(&:leads).flatten.count
```

Above able to give me all the leads from store id 1.  I also figured it out how to get ALL the leads of ALL stores from the last 7 days:

```
Lead.where(created_at: 7.days.ago..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).count
```

I would like to know how I can combine these two together and get the result only display the lead (or lead's count) from the last 7 days of each store. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier, associate leads with stores using [`has_many :through`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association.

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
    has_many :leads, through: :users
end
```

Then you should be able to query leads directly on stores:

```
s1 = Store.find(1)
s1.leads.where(created_at: 7.days.ago..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).count
```